# How to combine elements in list to a new nested list?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

I have a list 'r' like this:

```
[["", 1], ["this is a text line", 2], ["this is a text line", 3], ["this is a text line", 4], ["", 5], ["", 6], ["this is a text line", 7],["this is a text line", 8], ["this is a text line", 9], ["this is a text line", 10], ["", 11], ["this is a text line", 12], ["this is a text line", 13], ["this is a text line", 14], ["", 15], ["this is a text line", 16], ["this is a text line", 17], ["this is a text line", 18], ["", 19]]
```

To know where are my empty lines and lines with text I filter my list:

```
empty = [x[1] for x in r if regex.search("^\s*$", x[0])]
text = [x[1] for x in r if regex.search("\S", x[0])]
```

output:

```
empty = [1, 5, 6, 11, 15, 19]
text= [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18]
```

What I want to do is to combine the numbers in text if they are in sequence (text[i]-text[i+1]) = +1 (in order to define the paragraphs):

```
finaltext = [[2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [16, 17, 18]]
finaltext including empty = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

How can I group elements in a list based on a condition?

Comment: Do you need `finaltext` and `finaltext_including_empty` or only the last one? Why does the first sublist of `finaltext_including_empty` not start with a 1?

Comment: I need both lists. The first sublist does not start with 1 because I don't considerate empty lines at start of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pure Python solution without any `modules`:**

This can be done using `modules` such as with `numpy` and `groupby`, but I thought it would be call to attempt without them, just with plain `Python`. Here is my solution:

```
text = [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18]
s = 0
finaltext = []
for i in range(len(text)-1):
    if text[i] + 1 != text[i+1]:
        finaltext.append(text[s:i+1])
        s = i+1

finaltext.append(text[s:])
```

which gives `finaltext` as:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [16, 17, 18]]
```

---

**Update**

To get both of the `lists` (not sure why you would want to), you can use the following:

```
empty = [1, 5, 6, 11, 15, 19]
text = [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18]
s = 0
finaltext = []
finaltext_including_empty = []
for i in range(len(text)-1):
    if text[i] + 1 != text[i+1]:
        finaltext.append(text[s:i+1])
        finaltext_including_empty.append(list(range(text[s], text[i+1])))
        s = i+1

finaltext.append(text[s:])
finaltext_including_empty.append(list(range(text[s],max(empty[-1]+1, text[-1]+1))))
```

which gives `finaltext` the same as before and `finaltext_including_empty` as:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Comment: This is not the desired op. the last sublist should be [16,17,18]

Comment: @sharatpc sorry about that, that was just a little mistake in the last line that I hadn't picked up, take a look now - I'm open to any other problems **:)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very simple and nice. However.. in 'finaltext_including_empty' 19 is missing.

Comment: @Reman, my bad, I didn't see why that was necessary, but I have now updated the answer to go to the end of the `empty` `list` (i.e. include the `19`) hope this helps!

Comment: @JoeIddon if you take [1, 5, 10, 15, 20] as empty list and [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21] as text list it gives a wrong 'finaltext_including_empty' output. 21 is not included

Comment: @JoeIddon and with [5, 10, 15, 20] as empty list and [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21] as text list, the output is totally wrong

Comment: @Reman I have updated the answer now so that the `finaltext_including_empty` includes the `21` with that input and the second example you gave works correctly. Hopefully all works well for you too now **:)**

Answer (score 3):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest
grp_list = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(r, lambda x:x[0]=='')]
grp_list = grp_list[1:] if r[0][0] == '' else grp_list
text = [[j[1] for j in i] for i in grp_list]

finaltext = text[::2]
print (finaltext)
#[[2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [16, 17, 18]]

finaltext_including_empty = [i+j for i,j in zip_longest(text[::2], text[1::2], fillvalue=[])]
print (finaltext_including_empty)
#[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

`groupby` groups the  list into chunks of sublists based on condition which here is `lambda x:x[0]==''`, meaning create a list chunk till the point where you see an empty string, and follow this rule till the end like below

```
[[['', 1]], [['this is a text line', 2], ['this is a text line', 3], ['this is a text line', 4]], [['', 5], ['', 6]],........]
```

Comment: Charming. Am little curious why groupby creates 9 groups instead of 2: empty and non-empty?

Comment: Please see my comment on groupby

Comment: Thanks for your solution! However I noted that if the first line of my example list is text, it doesn't work anymore. (finaltext captures the empty lines [1::2])

Comment: @TransHumanist, there is still something not working. Please take the empty list [1, 5, 10, 15, 20] and the text list [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21]. Then using your solution it gives this results as finallist:  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9], [11, 12, 13, 14], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]. A few spaces are included (1 and 20 must not be in the list)

Comment: ok, edited now to include zip_longest, you should see it. let me know.

Comment: @TransHumanist, hope you don't mind if I haven't chosen your solution. Both are great solutions but the Joe Iddon one's is easier to understand. That has nothing to do with you, but with my limited knowledge. ;)

Comment: Reman - upvote? nevermind :).. i enjoyed answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

pip install more_itertools

```
from more_itertools import chunked

empty = [1, 5, 6, 11, 15, 19]
text= [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18]

finaltext_ = sorted(empty + text)

list(chunked(finaltext_,4))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19]]
```

Comment: Op is invalid. Asker didn't want the two lists combined, but numbers in text chunked into subsequences. Hard-coding the chunk size as 4? What if text comprised unequal sized chunks?